# PHP, MySQL HTML error in result

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello to everyone I'm new to this and I'm trying to make a simple dynamic HTML. I have written the following code but it seems dose not work. Can someone help me. Because All I get is the following line

```
$row[name]"); echo (""); echo (""); echo (""); echo (""); } ?>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">EDIT DATA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <table border="1">
  <?
  mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
  mysql_select_db("Computers");
  $order = "SELECT * FROM vnc";
  $result = mysql_query($order);

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo ("<td>$row[name]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[department]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[phone]</td>");
    echo ("<td>$row[ip]</td>");
    echo ("<td><a href="edit_form.php?id=$row[id]">Edit</a></td></tr>");
  }
  ?>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try switching from the short `<?` tag to `<?php`. Also, that's not the best way to access an array variable in a string - try `echo ("<td>" . $row['name']. "</td>");`

Comment: I disagree with what @andrewsi says about "the best way to access an array variable in a string," but do give the `<?php` a shot

Comment: @ExplosionPills - I didn't say that mine was the best; but I do find it the easiest to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td align="center">EDIT DATA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
  <table border="1">
  <?php
  mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
  mysql_select_db("Computers");
  $order = "SELECT * FROM vnc";
  $result = mysql_query($order);

  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<td>" . $row[name] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[department] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[phone] . "</td>
<td>" . $row[ip] . "</td>
<td><a href="edit_form.php?id=" . $row[id] . ">Edit</a></td></tr>";
  }
  ?>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: be careful, the url is surrounded by double quote. Escape them or replace them with single quote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you used the parenthesis, but what you're looking for is something similar to this:

```
echo "<td>" . $row[name] . "</td>";
```

Anything written inside the quotations will be displayed explicitly, which is why you have to end the quotes, add a period, then give the array, followed by another period and opening quotes.

The

Comment: because of variable interpolation `echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";` will do what the user is wanting. Single quotes around a string prevent variable interpolation.

Comment: thank you for the quick respond. What I get now is: " . $row[name] . ""; echo ""; echo ""; echo ""; } ?>

Comment: @Orangepill bad idea, because of []. `echo "<td>{$row[name]}</td>";` is better

Comment: Both good points, which is why I usually stick with concatenation.

Comment: My answer wins as it has the most comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

`<?` should be `<?php` .... It apprears that short tags is turned off on your webserver. also echo does not need parentheses

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is this:

```
echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
```

If your queries are working well, it should print something.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ("<td><a href="edit_form.php?id=$row[id]">Edit</a></td></tr>");
```

This line is problematic. You're trying to print double quotes in a double-quoted string. Try using single quotes instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are some sintax error in your code you don't need to use parethesis

```
echo "<td>$row[name]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[department]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[phone]</td>";
echo "<td>$row[ip]</td>";
```

Also this line needs to be fixed because of double quotes used in anchor, you can either change to single quote or escape it with a backslash

```
echo '<td><a href="edit_form.php?id=$row[id]">Edit</a></td>';
```

Or

```
echo "<td><a href=\"edit_form.php?id=$row[id]\">Edit</a></td>";
```

I would finally advise you to switch to long tags `<?php`

Comment: thank you the problem was because I used only <? instead of <?php

Comment: @Dimitrios you welcome. Don't forget to accept answer if it was correct for help people in the future with similar problems